# Android load full image with recyclerview, cardview and volley from php mysql

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

The code below downloads images from a server and displays them in a recyclerview using php mysql and volley library as seen in the attached image. As of now when one clicks the image only toasts the image name. I want a user to be able to view the full image on click. Sorry to post all the code but its a desperate situation.

[image: running application]

RecyclerView code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

CardView code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ECEFF1">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/VolleyImageView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ImageNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/VolleyImageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/VolleyImageView"
            android:text="JSon Image Name"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.ny.fetchallimages;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import java.util.List;

import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<DataAdapter> ListOfdataAdapter;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    String HTTP_JSON_URL = "http://*************.php";

    String Image_URL_JSON = "image_data";

    String Image_Name_JSON = "image_tag";

    JsonArrayRequest RequestOfJSonArray ;

    RequestQueue requestQueue ;

    View view ;

    int RecyclerViewItemPosition ;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerOfrecyclerView;

    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

    ArrayList<String> ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick = new ArrayList<>();

        ListOfdataAdapter = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManagerOfrecyclerView = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerOfrecyclerView);

        JSON_HTTP_CALL();

        // Implementing Click Listener on RecyclerView.
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    return true;
                }

            });
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                view = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                if(view != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {

                    //Getting RecyclerView Clicked Item value.
                    RecyclerViewItemPosition = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

                    // Showing RecyclerView Clicked Item value using Toast.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.get(RecyclerViewItemPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });


    }

    public void JSON_HTTP_CALL(){

        RequestOfJSonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(HTTP_JSON_URL,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        ParseJSonResponse(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        requestQueue.add(RequestOfJSonArray);
    }

    public void ParseJSonResponse(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            DataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new DataAdapter();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {

                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitle(json.getString(Image_Name_JSON));

                // Adding image title name in array to display on RecyclerView click event.
                ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.add(json.getString(Image_Name_JSON));

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageUrl(json.getString(Image_URL_JSON));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ListOfdataAdapter.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }

        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ListOfdataAdapter, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter

```
package com.ny.fetchallimages;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import java.util.List;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    List<DataAdapter> dataAdapters;

    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<DataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){

        super();
        this.dataAdapters = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

        DataAdapter dataAdapterOBJ =  dataAdapters.get(position);

        imageLoader = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        imageLoader.get(dataAdapterOBJ.getImageUrl(),
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                        Viewholder.VollyImageView,//Server Image
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
                )
        );

        Viewholder.VollyImageView.setImageUrl(dataAdapterOBJ.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);

        Viewholder.ImageTitleTextView.setText(dataAdapterOBJ.getImageTitle());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return dataAdapters.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView ImageTitleTextView;
        public NetworkImageView VollyImageView ;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            ImageTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageNameTextView) ;

            VollyImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VolleyImageView) ;

        }
    }
}
```

ImageAdapter

```
package com.ny.fetchallimages;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import android.content.Context;;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.Cache;
import androidx.collection.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.Network;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;

public class ImageAdapter {

    public static ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    public Network networkOBJ ;

    public RequestQueue requestQueue1;

    public ImageLoader Imageloader1;

    public Cache cache1 ;

    public static Context context1;

    LruCache<String, Bitmap> LRUCACHE = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(30);

    private ImageAdapter(Context context) {

        this.context1 = context;

        this.requestQueue1 = RequestQueueFunction();

        Imageloader1 = new ImageLoader(requestQueue1, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String URL) {

                return LRUCACHE.get(URL);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {

                LRUCACHE.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {

        return Imageloader1;
    }

    public static ImageAdapter getInstance(Context SynchronizedContext) {

        if (imageAdapter == null) {

            imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(SynchronizedContext);
        }
        return imageAdapter;
    }

    public RequestQueue RequestQueueFunction() {

        if (requestQueue1 == null) {

            cache1 = new DiskBasedCache(context1.getCacheDir());

            networkOBJ = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

            requestQueue1 = new RequestQueue(cache1, networkOBJ);

            requestQueue1.start();
        }
        return requestQueue1;
    }
}
```

DataAdapter

```
package com.ny.fetchallimages;

public class DataAdapter
{
    public String ImageURL;
    public String ImageTitle;

    public String getImageUrl() {

        return ImageURL;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageServerUrl) {

        this.ImageURL = imageServerUrl;
    }

    public String getImageTitle() {

        return ImageTitle;
    }

    public void setImageTitle(String Imagetitlename) {

        this.ImageTitle = Imagetitlename;
    }

}
```

Comment: Create another activity, then in on item click, get the item clicked position URL, send an intent to the activity with the image URL as extras. Get the image url from the intent in the activity then load the image.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Wojuola Ayotola. Kindly specify exactly how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked by creating a new activity, then in on item click, get the item clicked position URL, send an intent to the activity with the image URL as extras. Get the image url from the intent in the activity then load the image.